# Blend 5 (preview) missing Platform/resolution tab for WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, device, tablet, blend

Developing a WPF-application in Expression Blend for Visual Studio, I read that Blend now has the ability to emulate different resolution/dpi and orientations: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx

However, I can't seem to find the PlatformTab they mention:

[image: Blend screencap]

Does it not apply to WPF? I'm developing for an 10-inch Windows 8-tablet, but don't have access to the actual device yet. And I'm not sure I get the sizes correct.
Are there alternatives for WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform pane is only available for HTML and XAML Windows Store apps.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there are any alternatives for WPF?